# Writing the use of any computing device determine the value of the following

Tags: linear-algebra

[image]

I need help with this question, I don't know how to get the value without using a calculator or a computing device.

Comment: *Hint:* $\sin$ can be rewritten using $e^x$'s and the like.  The numerator and denominator can be expressed using geometric series.

Answer (score 0):

Recall that $\cos^2\alpha=\frac12(1+\cos2\alpha)$. Hence the denominator is in fact
$$45+\frac12(\cos2^\circ+\cos 4^\circ+\cdots+\cos 178^\circ+\cos 180^\circ) $$
Here, $\cos178^\circ=-\cos2^\circ$ etc. so that all we are left with in the denominator is
$$45+\frac12(\cos90^\circ+\cos 180^\circ)=44\frac12. $$
For the numerator note that $\sin ^2 \alpha+\cos^2\alpha=1$, hence the numerator is $90$ minus the denominator.